# Edit one list along with others in list of lists

Tags: c#, list

I get an SQL response and record it into list of lists, representing table of results. After that I need to for example distinct values in the first "column" (first list in my list of lists). How to tie all other lists to the first one so all "rows" are stay consistent and somehow connected by index number?
Number of columns (lists) is variable.

Here is code I use to get data from SQL response:

```
List<List<string>> response = new List<List<string>>();
int colNum = 0;

using (OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(query, con))
{
    using (OracleDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader()) // execute the oracle sql and start reading it
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            if (response.Count == 0)
            {
                while (rdr.GetOracleValue(colNum) != null)
                {
                    response.Add(new List<string>());
                    colNum++;
                }
            }
                for (int c = 0; c < colNum; c++)
                {
                    if (rdr.GetOracleValue(c).ToString() == "Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleClob")
                    {
                        response[c].AddRange(report.getPropertiesByName(rdr.GetOracleValue(c), "Value", false, false).Select(p => p.ToString()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response[c].Add(rdr.GetOracleValue(c).ToString());
                    }
            }
        }
        rdr.Close();
    }
}
return response;
```

Comment: What is the current code you are using to put the SQL data into lists?

Comment: Post code or we can't help you.

Comment: I think you should use a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) for this along with [OracleDataReader.GetSchemaTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.getschematable.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`OracleDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter.aspx). I'm not quite sure if this syntax is correct, but it should get you started.

```
var response = new DataSet();

using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query, con))
{
    var dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
    dataAdapter.Fill(response); 
}

return response;
```